# Active a function when Key hit/pressed in InputBox in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events, keyevent

I want when a user will hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key in INPUT BOX a function will be activate. Something like below:

```
if (ENTERKEY is Pressed in INPUTBOX){
    Function(){....
    }
};
```

This is Input box:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="second_gear"/>
```

to trigger this function after hitting the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key:

```
jump = function () {
       //do...........
       //do.....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#INPUTBOX" ).focus(function() {
    function (event) {
                if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
                    //code here
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
```

Comment: Your code will work when user hit the Enter. But what I want is not that. I want if ENTER is Hit only within InputBox.

Comment: I use a bit of jquery or if you want pure javascript use document.activeElement.